# What can be the reason for attribute of domain class not being recognized in grails template?

Tags: templates, grails

I have a Grails template `_questionForm.gsp`. However, the `question` (which is an attribute of `Question` domain class) is not being recognized in this template. What can be the reason?

**_questionForm.gsp**

```
<g:form action="addQuestions" controller="dashboard" method="post">
    <br/>
     Question: <g:textArea name="question" required="required" value="${questionInstance?.question}"/> <br/> //.question not recognized here

    <!--For Options-->
    <g:each in="${(1..<5)}" var="i">
        Option ${i} : <g:textField name="option${i}" required="required" class="options"/> <br/>
    </g:each>

    Subject: <g:select name="questionSubject"
                       from="${com.dwit.research.begnas.api.Subject.list()}"
                       optionValue="subject"
                       optionKey="id" noSelection="['':'Choose Subject']" required="required"/>
    <br/><br/>

    <em>Correct Answer: </em><br/>
    <!--For correct answer-->
    <g:each in="${(1..<5)}" var="i">
        <input type="radio" name="correct_answer" value="${i}" id="rdo_option${i}"/> <label for="rdo_option${i}">Option ${i}</label><br/>
    </g:each>
    <br/>
    <g:submitButton name="Next"/>
</g:form>
```

Question (domain class)

package com.dwit.research.begnas.api

class Question {

```
String question
Boolean isSkipped = false
Subject subject

static constraints = {
}
```

}

Comment: It might help if you include your Domain class with your question.

Comment: What is happening or are you getting any error?

Comment: No such property: question for class: java.lang.String : this is the error that I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `questionInstance` variable is set to a `String` rather than an instance of `Question`.

1. Look at the controller which renders `_questionForm.gsp`.
2. There's likely a `render()` method call which sets the view and model.
3. Change `model.questionInstance` to an instance of `Question`.